# Find the best representative substrings from many strings

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Lets say we have strings in group 1:

`list`, `list of discount offers`, `specific discount offers`, `discount offer`, `discount offer details`

and for exmple another set of strings in group 2:

`Add to basket button`, `basket button`, `Add`

What I want to achieve is select a representative from each group. Each group representative should be selected by the most common substring from the group but not leaving out unique strings.

For example, in group 1, I would say the representatives are `list of discount offers`, `specific discount offers`, `discount offer details`. In group 2 it should be `Add to basket button` because it contains both strings, even though `add` and `basket button` occur two times each in total.

Is there some function in python which fits the best for such thing? I haven't been able to find anything  reasonable.

Comment: Why the second group representative is `Add to basket button`? Both `Add` and `basket button` are present two times.

Comment: Because `Add to basket button` contains both strings.

Comment: By that logic `specific discount offers`, `list of discount offers` and `discount offer details` are better representatives for group 1.

Comment: This suggestion could be also sufficient for what I need, yes.

Comment: You need to rewrite the question, it's vague.

Comment: Okay, now it should be what we have discussed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Counter class from collections should be useful for this kind of work.  Assuming you're not looking for nGrams counts to make the selection, you could build a dictionary of number of expressions that contain each word.  Then add up these counts for words in each expression to give it a relative weight (preferably not counting the expression itself in the weight).  The expression(s) with the highest weight should be the representative(s).

```
from collections import Counter

def represent(group):
    groupWords = [ expr.split(" ") for expr in group ]
    wordFreq   = Counter(word for words in groupWords for word in words)
    weights    = [ sum(wordFreq[word] for word in words)-len(words) for words in groupWords ]
    maxWeight  = max(weights)
    return [ (expr,weight) for expr,weight in zip(group,weights) if weight == maxWeight]
```

output: (expressions and weights)

```
group1 = ["list", "list of discount offers", "specific discount offers",
          "discount offer", "discount offer details"]

print(represent(group1))
# [('list of discount offers', 5)]


group2 = ["Add to basket button", "basket button", "Add"]

print(represent(group2))
# [('Add to basket button', 3)]
```